# Getting a syntax error on a system generated file while working with django! How to fix it?

Tags: django, syntax-error

While I am setting up a supeuser in my django project using the command

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

manage.py is a system generated file still it shows a syntax error.
Here is the manage.py file! -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 
"my_django15_project.settings")
   try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Please tell some solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `from` part of `raise` is not supported in Python 2.x. Use Python 3.x instead.